# partial fractions with numerator and denominator of the same degree

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

I tried using partial fractions but wasn't sure what to do with the ${x^2}$:
$$\int \frac{x^2}{3x^2 - 4} dx$$

Comment: Consider including your work in the question so that others have the chance to provide constructive feed back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to do long division (when numerator  and denominator have the same degree):

$$\frac {x^2}{3x^2-4} = \frac 1 3 + \frac{4}{3} \frac {1}{3x^2-4}.$$

Now you can do partial fractions on the second term (you should factor the denominator into two linear terms).

Comment: √3/9 ln|(x-2/√3)/(x+2/√3)|+1/3 x+C I tried to solve the way you said me but I'm not sure whether answer is true. Can you check it please? :)

Comment: @dummy Yes, this is correct. You can always check that your answer is true using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E2%2F%283x%5E2-4%29)

Comment: @dummy you are welcome!